Download fails on SSH Amazon Linux 2023
Trying to download dokuwiki on Amazon Linux 2023 version 2023.6.20241212 via SSH.
wget https://download.dokuwiki.org/src/dokuwiki/dokuwiki-stable.tgz

but it returns
https://download.dokuwiki.org/src/dokuwiki/dokuwiki-stable.tgz
Resolving download.dokuwiki.org (download.dokuwiki.org)... 2a01:4f8:172:3483::2, 138.201.13
7.132
Connecting to download.dokuwiki.org (download.dokuwiki.org)|2a01:4f8:172:3483::2|:443... co
nnected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4206676 (4.0M) [application/octet-stream]
dokuwiki-stable.tgz: Permission denied

Cannot write to ‘dokuwiki-stable.tgz’ (Permission denied).

What am I doing wrong?

Some websites block IP addresses associated with Amazon EC2 instances, so this might be the cause.

It appears that you are trying to save to a directory to which you do not have write permission. Try changing to your home directory (cd) and then running the command, or run with sudo.
